# Sum only matched values from two columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

[image]

Hello Everyone,

Does anyone know how to sum the Hours from column B (Hours) if column A numbers matched with column E and sum by months.

Example, take February data as an example, since only 3000 & 4000 existed in both column A & column E, that's why I need to sum the hours (20+10=30) from column B by it's month below.

I also attached the example excel sheet below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0s51g1i8g6s6e2d/Test.xls?m

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get complicated with customer functions but if having an extra column (potentially hidden) doesn't matter then this would work:

In cell D2 enter:

```
=iferror(vlookup($A2,$E$2:$E$20,1,FALSE),"x")
```

Drag the formula down.

Under each month you can then put:

```
=sumifs($B$2:$B$16,$C$2:$C$16,B$22,$D$2:$D$16,"<>x")
```

Drag the formula across

This assumes you can change the month format in either column C or row 22 to be the same, ie. Jan, Feb, Mar or January, February, March etc.

Written on the fly and not tested so excuse any minor errors...

Comment: slightly different method than I used but should give, same results -- make sure to autofill the formula under each month to preserve the relative reference to `B$22`.

Comment: Shows the speed of responses on here, there was no answer when I started typing and by the time I posted... I'll work on my typing speed.

Comment: Thanks both David and Simon.

Comment: Hi David & Simon, does any of you know why if the number come from other cell then your formula will not working. Please check out my updated excel for example. Thanks https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ip6j7gl4021a3g/Test.xlsx?m

Comment: Hi James, it is to do with the format of the numbers in column C - Excel thinks they are text, not numbers (them being left aligned is the giveaway). Easiest way round this is to change the formula in column F to: '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2*1,'S1'!$H$2:$H$20,1,FALSE),"x")' though you may want to change the formatting also.

Comment: Hi Simon, I have to admire you since you can work out the solution on the go. So Amazing... Thanks a lot and that works!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in Cell D2 and drag down:

`=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$20,FALSE))),B2,"")`

In row 22, change the month names to be the full name, **OR** in column C, change the month names to abbreviated 3-letter names, this is so we can make use of the `SumIf` function.

Then, in Cell B23, put this formula and drag it across:

`=SUMIF($C$2:$C$16,B22,$D$2:$D$16)`

(I put the formula in row 24 to check against the data you already had in Row 23)

[image: Screenshot of SumIf function results]

Comment: Wow, that was quick, it's works and thanks so so much David. :-)

Comment: Hi David & Simon, does any of you know why if the number come from other cell then your formula will not working. Please check out my updated excel for example. Thanks dropbox.com/s/2ip6j7gl4021a3g/Test.xlsx?m

Comment: The data in B2 and column C is formatted as text while column H is formatted as number (note: you can't change that just by changing formatting), you could change the VLOOKUP formula to this in F2 copied down `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2+0,'S1'!$H$2:$H$20,1,FALSE),"x")` - the +0 converts text to number and now that should work - Note that my SUMPRODUCT/SUMIFS suggestion works (when you adjust cell references to fit your layout) whether the data is text or numeric because SUMIFS is less fussy about matching text and numbers than VLOOKUP

Comment: @ David Zemens - SUMIF formula should have `$C$2:$C$16` as first range otherwise formula as written (in the answer text) will sum numbers in column E

Comment: @barryhoudini not sure what makes you think this formula `=SUMIF($B$2:$C$16,B22,$D$2:$D$16)` is summing from column E... changing the first range argument to `$C$2:$C$16` does not alter the results although I agree that should be changed.

Comment: SUMIF always uses a sum range that is the same size as the criteria range, starting from the top left cell of the actual range you specify (D2 in this case), so that formula is equivalent to `=SUMIF($B$2:$C$16,B22,$D$2:$E$16)` - try using on an empty sheet make B22 = "x" and C2 = "x" - D2 = 5, E2 = 100 - formula returns 100

Comment: Duly noted, typo has been revised. I notice my formula in worksheet is C2, not B2. Must have mistyped when inputting here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers posted thus far are just fine, but just as an alternative, here's what I would do.  Put this formula in cell D2 and drag it down:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2, $E$2:$E$20, 1, FALSE))), B2, "")
```

Then if you make a column containing the names of the months, say from G2 to G7 you have February, March, ..., July, you can put this formula into H2 and drag it down:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$16, $C$2:$C$16, G2)
```

That should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be much harder without a helper column. Just make sure you have full month name in row 22 to match column C data then use this formula in B23 copied across

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($B2:$B16,$C2:$C16,B22,$A2:$A16,$E2:$E20))`